# Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition Installer can't start

Tags: visual-studio

I tried to upgrade my Visual Studio 2019 Community edition, but the Visual Studio Installer can't start.

I tried a lot of things including uninstalling the existing version, using offline version, etc, but now I end up with no working version of Visual Studio.

This is the log from bootstrapper:

```
Beginning of the log. Start Time: 2019-05-25 10:04:39
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:40: Commandline arguments = --env,_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:E:\Download\vs_community.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:E:\Download
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:40: Parent process name = vs_community
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:40: Parent process product version = 16.1.28922.388
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:40: CampaignId = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:40: ResponseId not available in 'vs_setup_bootstrapper.config'. Trying to parse filename.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:40: loading config settings: -update --update --layout -offline --offline --locale --layout --originalworkingdir --installLayoutPath --env
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:45: DownloadURL = https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:45: InstallLocation = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:45: OfflineFilePath = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:45: LayoutLocation = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:45: ExecutableArguments = /finalizeInstall install --in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_setup_bootstrapper_201905251004409923.json" --locale en-US --activityId "65140cc5-fa4c-470e-9740-8005502ed51e"
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:45: OSVersion = Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:45: Starting to detect the existing VS and .NET...
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:04:45: Finished detecting the existing VS and .Net
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:05:04: Beginning file download. File = https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:05:04: Download requested: https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:05:05: Attempting download 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer' using engine 'WebClient'
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:05:05: Uri 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer' redirected to 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/8e169392-7f87-4d2e-a6e9-0c510272d9df/d4e01b060095407608d193d7143f6e4a/vs_installer.opc'
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:18: Package signature verification returned Success for path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\d.uhy\vs_installer.opc
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:18: Download of 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:18: Current OptIn value is 1
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:18: Extracting file 'vs_installer.version.json' from package stream.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:18: File found 'vs_installer.version.json' in package stream.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:18: Comparing client candidate version '2.1.3125.514' to autoSelfUpdateMinVersion '2.1.3125.514'
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:22: Beginning extracting files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:22: Extracting 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_installer\d.uhy\vs_installer.opc' to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer'.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:26: Successfully extracted 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer'.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:26: Start named pipe: 91ba8373-9502-45d1-8629-a80eadc83d01
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:26: Starting VS setup process 'vs_installer.exe' with arguments '/finalizeInstall install --in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_setup_bootstrapper_201905251004409923.json" --locale en-US --activityId "65140cc5-fa4c-470e-9740-8005502ed51e" --pipe "91ba8373-9502-45d1-8629-a80eadc83d01"'.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:26: VS setup process C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe started. All done.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:11:26: VS setup process starting. Exiting with code 0
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:12:06: Pipe disconnected.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:2019-05-25 10:12:06: Bootstrapper Successfully completed.
```

I hope someone can help me find the solution.

Comment: Maybe try: [InstallCleanup.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). And there is [this blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/cleaning-up-corrupt-visual-studio-instances/). And [the troubleshooter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2019).

Comment: If all fails, maybe use a virtual? Obvious yes, just a reminder - can help in a pinch. Also easier to use for future testing of updates before you upgrade your main box? Takes forever to install though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried installCleanup and also didn't work. I didn't have time for more trials and errors, so I reinstalled the windows and the visual studio.

Comment: Probably a good idea to do that, yes. One last comment: I once installed Visual Studio without any options added on a virtual. I then added individual packages: **`.NET Framework 3.5 Development Tools`** and **`.NET Compiler Platform SDK`**. This was enough for me to get WiX running (yes, I added WiX and Votive as the last packages), and I had a simple, light Visual Studio version to test upgrades on (essentially just the Visual Studio Editor GUI and Votive). Might be useful? Just thought I'd mention it. Might be different in 2019 - I used 2017.

Answer (score 9):

There can be some troubles with the certificates on vs_installer.exe and vs_installershell.exe. Installing this [KB3004394](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3004394/support-for-urgent-trusted-root-updates-for-windows-root-certificate-p) may help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24530085)

Comment: I just wanted to share the way I've solved exactly this issue and others can save a couple of hours. You are free to delete it if you think it's not useful.
Btw, there is no any question in asker's post - only his hopes.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me. It worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: This answer solved my problem too. I'm on Windows 7-x64-SP1. Thank you! @Seishin

Comment: Just wanted to say Me too! Worked perfectly (Win 7 Home Premium x86), thanks for your answer. Original problem: "error while downloading files" in installer

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue. I read about renaming the folder '/installer' but it didn't work for me. I ended removing the file 'vs_installer.exe' and I used one of the down-loaders.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srywK.png)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem this evening while trying to install Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition on my laptop (Windows 10 Pro Build 19042). After nearly one hour of desperately trying out various scenarios (including messing with Component Services and adding my user to Local Access rights for COM+ Apps), I got it to work by simply moving the installer file from my "Downloads" folder to another place on the disk. Then, it worked.

That pointed out the installer is unable to start if run from a path/folder that has UTF-8 characters in its name (I was using "C:\Users\Dragoș\Downloads" initially). Since this proved to reproduce each time I placed the installer in any folder containing UTF-8 chars, I filed a bug report at Microsoft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2019-installer-does-not-st/1411874

I do not know if this scenario matches your context, but anyhow, I hope it helps somebody along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried renaming the vs_installer.exe to vs_installer.old, and that did not work for me.  When I unchecked the "Keep download cache after the installation" on the Installation tab, then the Close button changed to Modify.